# Netlogo Local Optimization

Tags: optimization, local, netlogo, logical-operators

I want to estimate the demand for a new product. customers are the agents. Each product has 3 variables that need to be optimized based on the purchases. In order to find the optimum variables that maximize the sales, I used a local optimization algorithm, the gradient descent. It works as follows :

1.Initial value for weight, size, and price are defined.
2. The search procedure starts :
dgradient is the norm of the gradient of the objective function. dx calculated the difference between a variable and a new variable.

```
 while [dgradient > 0.00001 and numiter < 1000 and dxw > 0.00001 and dxs > 0.00001 and dxp > 0.00001]

set weightnw weight - stepsize * (the gradient)
set sizenw size - stepsize * (the gradient)
setpricenw price - stepsize * (the gradient)
```

The search procedure, produces new variables in the neighborhood, but I have to make sure they are in the range. So I defined this while loop to make sure they are in range :

```
 while [not(((weightnw <= 400) and (weightnw >= 100)) and ((sizenw >= 5) and sizenw <= 20)) and ((pricenw >= 20) and (pricenw <=90)))] 
set stepsize stepsize - 0.0001
 set weightnw weight - stepsize * (the gradient)
set sizenw size - stepsize * (the gradient)
setpricenw price - stepsize * (the gradient)
```

Then the objective function is calculated and the value of objective function with the new variable is compared.

Does the procedure make sense?

Thanks

Comment: How is the gradient computed? Why not just use hill-climbing with restarts or some search algorithm like that? See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/gradient

Comment: Also, what is the issue that you're experiencing? Is the expected value off? I *think* you may be finding a local minimal/maximum rather than global, but it really depends on the rest of the code that's not shown.

Answer (score 4):

The `numanal` extension includes several methods for optimizing a multi-variate problem, including the simplex method and more esoteric methods such as CMAES and BOBYQA. They do allow the setting of bounds. It's not quite ready for NetLogo 6.0 (there is a working version for 5.3), but if you think that it might be useful, let me know and I can ship you a beta.

Charles

Comment: Can you send me the latest version of numanal. I plan to wrap up some lectures on optimisation and plan to use NetLogo kalin.stoyanov@uctm.edu

Comment: Sorry to take so long.  The extension for NetLogo 6.1 is available here: https://github.com/cstaelin/NumAnal-Extension , and I've sent it to your email.  It appears to work fine with NetLogo 6.2.